# FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions returns FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

Im trying to understand something...

What happens is when `openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions` is called for the first time, I get the `FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed` state.
However the next time i call the `openActiveSession`.. the state becomes `FBSessionStateOpen`.

So i am trying to understand why it is returning loginfailed the first time i call the method.

All help is appreciated.

```
+(void)startFacebookSessionState:(void (^)(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error))completionBlock
{

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if ([[FBSession activeSession] isOpen])
        completionBlock(YES, nil);
    else
    {
        NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email", @"user_friends", @"user_photos", @"publish_actions", nil];

        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:
         ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error)
         {
             [appDelegate sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
             if(!error)
                 completionBlock(YES, error);
             else
                 completionBlock(NO, error);
         }];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I am also experiencing this. Is this an old method or something? I'm trying to understand if Facebook is playing fast and loose with its sdk. No telling if they've completely phased this "way" of logging in out in favor of... Facebook developers help?